# Fantasy book with a "sympathy" amulet that makes people more friendly to the protagonist

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book that I've read maybe 10/15 years ago (it might be older though), and I think it was fantasy.

The only element I remember is that at some point, the protagonist is given an amulet that has the power to make the wearer more likeable if the amulet is visible.  People will help him, be more friendly,...

Sometimes, he has to hide the amulet under his shirt so that the effects do not appear.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember anything about the appearance of the book?  (The cover art, overall colour, etc.?)

Comment: I have no idea, just asking a detail taht might help others: Why would he want to not show the Amulet? Is there a downside to the effects? Do you remember the downside stated or in effect during the book?

Comment: Closest I can think of at the moment is *The Neverending Story* where the Auryn amulet shows he's on an official quest, but he occasionally hids it so it's not obvious he's on a quest.

Comment: Likely not the answer but Regis the halfling companion of Drizzt has an amulet that he uses to confuse/hypnotise" people so he gets his way. Regis stole that amulet though, and keeps it hidden most of the time. The amulet first appears in "The Crystal Shard, book one of the lcewind Dale trilogy Forgotten Realms.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds like one of the Realm of the Elderling books by Robin Hobb. Specifically this would be [Fool's Errand](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/68488.Fool_s_Errand), the first book of the third trilogy, The Tawny Man.

> Prince Dutiful has gone missing just before his crucial diplomatic wedding to an Outislander princess. Fitz’s assignment to fetch Dutiful back in time for the ceremony.

In the chapter 'Charms' just over 1/3 of the way through a Hedge Witch called Jinna makes a charm for Fitz in the form of a necklace that is supposed to make people like him.

> 'This is a variation on a very old love charm. I have made it not to attract lovers, but to make people well disposed towards you, if it works as I hope it will. When you try to create a variation on a theme it often lacks strength. Sit still now.'
> She walked behind my chair with the dangling necklace...

While Fitz is wearing the charm at this initial setting, the witch who made it starts blushing while looking at him, while her much younger niece invites Fitz to stay for dinner. Jinna cautions him to keep it covered, but find an excuse to loosen his collar if he is in a situation where it may help.

Comment: +1 I *just* reread this last week, and the OP's questions screams *Fool's Errand* to me! And I for sure was going to post this answer if some worthy person had not already done so. :)

Comment: I would also add that sometimes Fitz/Tom Badgerlock hides the charm because he is uncomfortable with how it makes some people react to him.

Comment: I saw the question and became more and more excited as I went along; ‘finally, a question I can answer!’ — then I rapidly deflated when I realised you’d done it already :D nice answer though

Comment: @Fivesideddice and Lexible, it's good to know I can be a sniper as well as a snipee sometimes.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you :)